# How to pass "constant" arguments in a parallel mapping?

Tags: python, function, numpy, parallel-processing

I have been dealing the past few days with some problems where Variables that are defined within the main "program" are said to not be defined when I map a certain function.

Anyways, I thought the solution was to pass these variables as Arguments but even then I try to do it with a MWE, I fail!

It is probably something obvious so, sorry in advance for posting about this. Here it is:

The function:

```
def arar(a1,*a3):
    a2=[]
    a2.append(a1+a3[0])
    return(a2)
```

The result for a `testloop=np.array([1,2,3,4])`:

```
testloop = np.array([1,2,3,4])
args = 1
a4=[]
for i in testloop:
    a4.append(arar(i,args))
print a4
>>>[[2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

and the "parallel" attempt:

```
testloop = np.array([1,2,3,4])
import multiprocessing as mp
pool      = mp.Pool(4)
aaaa     = pool.map(arar,testloop)
print(aaaa)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

where the result is right, but I can't pass the `args` to the `map()` function so that I get `[2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: Use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to pass them and use the result as the function passed to `map()`.

Comment: could you possibly give an example? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) as I suggested in a comment:

```
from functools import partial
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np


def arar(a1, *a3):
    a2 = []
    a2.append(a1+a3[0])
    return a2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testloop = np.array([1,2,3,4])

    args = 1
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    aaaa = pool.map(partial(arar, args), testloop)
    print(aaaa)  # -> [[2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't really found an example that could help me.

Comment: I understand — it's kind of an advanced topic. Think of `partial` as simply a way to create a new function that has some of the arguments the original function requires predefined — so they don't have to be passed when calling the new one.